# Data Validation in R

Tags: r

I want to validate the header and the body of a .csv

You can find an image more explanatory: http://s2.subirimagenes.com/imagen/previo/thump_9815351ejemo-validar.png

I want to validate a table with a header with the next parameters: COL1=PERSONA, COL2=EDAD, COL3=SEXO, COL4=TRABAJO, COL5=MULTIPLICADOR, and validate the body with the next values in the columns:
COL1= VARCHAR, COL2= NUMERICAL, COL3= H or M(the values that compose the column could be H or M), COL4=VARCHAR, COL5= 1(all the values must be 1).

I want to charge the .csv archive in R and validate the .csv with code, and finally R give me a TRUE if the values of the .csv are right or FALSE if the values are wrong. I need that R validates the header and the body of the file.

How can I do it?

Thanks and kind regards,

Comment: Do you mean, that you want to load the table and see if the class of each variable fits with what you want both on type and possible values?

Comment: Yes, this is the question.

Answer (score 1):

Supposing you have loaded your file into `data` I will implement this function:

```
good.csv <- function(x){
 # We start asuming that everything is correct
   res <- T
 # Evaluate colnames
   if (sum(colnames(x)==c("PERSONA", "EDAD", "SEXO", "TRABAJO", "MULTIPLICADOR"))!=5){res <- F
} 
  if(!(class(x$PERSONA)%in%c("character","factor"))){res <- F}
  if(is.numeric(x$EDAD)==F){res <- F}
  if(!(levels(x$SEXO)%in%c("H","M"))){res <- F}
  if(!(class(x$TRABAJO)%in%c("character","factor"))){res <- F}
  if((x$MULTIPLICADOR)!=rep(1,nrow(x))){res <- F}
 # Return res value
   return(res)
}
```

Finally, run `good.csv(data)` to see if it is a good data set.